# Remove middle part from fasta file?

Tags: fasta

I have the fasta like this

```
>acc|AAM01497|Glutamate-1-semialdehyde aminotransferase [Methanopyrus kandleri AV19]|COG0001|H
MGYEDEFPESLELFKRAERVMPGGVSSPVRRFDPYPFYVERAEGSRLYTVDGHVLIDYCLAFGPLILGHAHPEVVEAVVERVREGFHYGTPTLPEL
>acc|AAM04025|glutamate-1-semialdehyde 2,1-aminomutase [Methanosarcina acetivorans C2A]|COG0001|H
MVSEVTLDKSRQMYEKAKTLIPGGVSSPVRAIKPYPFYTASADGSKIRDLDGNEYIDYCLAYGPAVLGHNHPVIKAAIKEQLDKGWLYGTPTELEV
```

I want the output like

```
>acc|AAM01497|COG0001|H
MGYEDEFPESLELFKRAERVMPGGVSSPVRRFDPYPFYVERAEGSRLYTVDGHVLIDYCLAFGPLILGHAHPEVVEAVVERVREGFHYGTPTLPEL
>acc|AAM04025|COG0001|H
MVSEVTLDKSRQMYEKAKTLIPGGVSSPVRAIKPYPFYTASADGSKIRDLDGNEYIDYCLAYGPAVLGHNHPVIKAAIKEQLDKGWLYGTPTELEV
```

Thank you for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

using python & biopython (its quite of long maybe somebody else can show it with perl or regex, I am trying to learn biopython), not kwowing if your fasta format is supported by biopython ( meaning the header of the fasta file):

```
from Bio import SeqIO
from Bio.SeqRecord import SeqRecord
from Bio.Seq import Seq
from Bio.SeqIO import FastaIO

input_file = 'test.faa'

output_file_name = 'output_'+input_file

input_fasta = []
output_fasta = []
for item in SeqIO.parse(input_file, 'fasta'):
    input_fasta.append(item)
print(input_fasta)
    
for item in input_fasta:
    print('\nitem : ',type(item),'\n',item,'\n',sep='')    
    s=(str((item.description).strip('')).split('|'))

    for i in s:
        print(i)
    output_description = 'acc|'+s[1]+'|'+s[3]+'|'+s[4]
    print('#######\n',output_description,sep='')
    # record = SeqRecord(Seq(str(item.seq)),id='',description=output_description) #this version has a space (' ') after >
    record = SeqRecord(Seq(str(item.seq)),id=output_description,description='')
    output_fasta.append(record)


fasta_out = FastaIO.FastaWriter(output_file_name, wrap=None) #this bit to write fasta sequence  as single line
fasta_out.write_file(output_fasta)
```

I left the print statements to figure out how the biopython SeqRecord object is composed and how the SeqIO parser reads your sequences fasta headers